# python - Django ORM retrieve parent model with filtered children model

Tags: python, django, database, filtering, relationship

I have the following models in Django:

```
class Gasto(models.Model):
  monto = models.DecimalField(default=0,decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  informacion = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
  numero_cuotas = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
  es_compartido = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  es_divisible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  contrato = models.ForeignKey(Contrato, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Cuota_Gasto(models.Model):
  monto = models.DecimalField(default=0,decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
  fecha = models.DateField()
  gasto = models.ForeignKey(Gasto, 
           related_name='cuotas',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  factura_rendida = models.ForeignKey(Factura, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, 
           null=True, related_name='gasto_rendido')
  factura_liquidada = models.ForeignKey(Factura, 
           on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, 
           related_name='gasto_liquidado')
```

From now on: 'Gasto' will be called **Expense**, and 'Cuota_Gasto' will be called **Share**.

Expense is the parent model and Share is the children, with a 1..N relationship.

I want to retrieve each Expense with its Shares, BUT only those Shares that meet certain conditions. Is this possible?

I could get each expense with ALL shares by using related_name and reverse relantionship, for example:

```
{
    "monto": "-500.00",
    "nombre": "RRR",
    "informacion": "Extra",
    "numero_cuotas": 1,
    "es_compartido": true,
    "cuotas": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "nombre": "RRR",
            "informacion": "Extra",
            "contrato": 3,
            "monto": "-500.00",
            "fecha": "07/07/2019",
            "gasto": 4,
            "factura_rendida": null,
            "factura_liquidada": 12
        }
    ]
}
```

But I can't get to the query that allows me to exclude the shares i don't want.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
Gasto.objects.distinct().filter(cuotas__fecha__lte = date)
```

Even though that query is not correct.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try `exclude` instead of `filter`. or in combination with each other. As in `.filter(...).exclude(...)`.

Comment: `queryset = queryset.filter(cuotas__fecha__gte = date).distinct()`

That query retrieves those Expenses which Shares meet the condition. But the result includes EVERY Share for that Expense, even those that doesn't meet the condition. Is there anyway I can exclude those?